# Password resets on reboot (multi-user network)

Tags: password

Today I attempted to log in to my work laptop and got an invalid credentials message. I was still able to log into the local admin and change the password. However, after rebooting, I get the same message and have to change the password again.

To me this is just bizarre, so I'm not really sure where to start diagnosing the problem.

Other quirks:

1. My own account was removed only from the sudo group (other groups were still present).
2. The account in question is not visible from the GDM login GUI. I added a test account and it is visible and can be logged into without the password reset dance.

**Version is 18.04**

Output of /etc/passwd and /etc/group. Account in question is my.name

https://pastebin.com/U9m9v3nW

**UPDATE**: I re-added the account to the sudo group and that change seems to be persisting through reboot.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you share the output of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` ? You can anonymize it if you like, I'm intrested in just the _home_ and _shell_ fields.

Comment: So you are authenticating via the network but changed your password with the local admin? It seem that with the next connection to the network the password is resyncronized with the central authentication server overruling your local changes.

Comment: I added a pastebin link

Comment: @Fiximan Yes I'm remembering now we use LDAP. I did connect to the LAN via VPN to see if it would fix anything, but that didn't work.

Comment: OK - were you able to log in while not being on the network before?

Comment: Yes, I have been able to log in both while connected to the company network, my home network, and no network at all.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer was that my LDAP password expired.